# How to assert that void method throws Exception using Mockito and catch-exception?

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to test this method:

```
public void deleteCurrentlyLoggedInUser(Principal principal) {
    if (findLoggedInUser(principal) == null) {
        throw new UserAlreadyDeletedException();
    }
    userRepository.delete(findLoggedInUser(principal));
}
```

Here is findLoggedInUser:

```
User findLoggedInUser(Principal principal) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());
}
```

And here is my test so far:

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenUserNotFound() {
    // given
    when(sut.findLoggedInUser(principalStub)).thenReturn(null);

    // when
    sut.deleteCurrentlyLoggedInUser(principalStub);

    // then
    catchException
    verify(userRepositoryMock, never()).delete(any(User.class));
}
```

So how do I catch exception using [catch-exception](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.catch-exception/catch-exception/1.2.0) here? Method that I'm testing returns void and I just can't seem to find a way to assert that exception was found.

EDIT: I know I could use: `@Test(expected = UserAlreadyDeletedException.class)` but I want to switch my whole project to catch-exception because it's much better and using expected in @Test is not very reasonable.

Comment: Don't use `expected = SomeException.class`. You don't have control or visibility over which expression in the method actually throws the exception. It is preferable to use `try/catch` over that, because then you can show exactly what you expect to do the throwing.

Comment: @AndyTurner I would argue that if you have more than one thing that could throw a `SomeException` in a single unit test, the said unit test needs to be split up.

Comment: @JoeC yes, but: except for the most simple tests, you are probably doing things to do your test case-specific setup; depending upon what you're catching, one of these setup actions might throw the same exception, giving the impression your test passes, when in fact it doesn't.

Comment: @JoeC for example: `@Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class) public void test() { new This().that(); }`: what throws the exception here? Either `new This()`, in which case the `.that()` is unnecessary and misleading; or `.that()`, in which case the try/catch should be around that, to ensure that expectations of the constructor succeeding are also validated.

Comment: I'm not using expected - I know about its issues - that's why I wanted to use catch-exception library but don't know how to with void methods.

Comment: @doublemc but you said "I know I could use" expected, and I'm saying that you shouldn't: `try/catch` is a better option.

Comment: But then I said "and using expected in @Test is not very reasonable.". Anyways, you are right, gonna go with your solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that using Rules is something that could work for you?

> Rules allow very flexible addition or redefinition of the behavior of each test method in a test class. Testers can reuse or extend one of the provided Rules below, or write their own.

You can read more about this neat feature of junit4 here:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules

Example:

```
public static class HasExpectedException {
    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void throwsNullPointerException() {
            thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
            throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of catch-exception, but it doesn't exactly seem like an up-to-date library: the last update to the main source code (at the time of writing) was [on May 3 2015](https://github.com/Codearte/catch-exception/tree/master/catch-exception/src).

If you're using Java 8, and can use JUnit 4.13 or later, you can use [`assertThrows`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L980):

```
assertThrows(
    UserAlreadyDeletedException.class,
    () -> sut.deleteCurrentlyLoggedInUser(principalStub));
```

If you're going to migrate all of your code to something, this seems like a better long-term bet.

Comment: Do you know how can I use Junit 4.13 when I'm using Spring Boot?  I can't see this version in Maven Repo yet.

Comment: This feature is also included with JUnit 5 as well, however, both 4.13 and 5.0 is not released publically yet (still in either RC or Snapshot verison). That's why you cannot find the versions on the official maven repo :).